# How long does a transfer IOTAs from the wallet to the exchange (Bitfinex) take?

Tags: transaction, wallet, pending, exchanges

Downloading IOTAs from the exchange to the wallet is somehow slow but in the end it works. Uploading just does not seem to work even using the *reattach* or *promote* options.

Answer (score 1):

When you transfer iota to bitfinex, you have to distinguish between 2 things:

- first you transfer iotas to your deposit address.
- second, bitfinex transfer iota from your deposit address to his wallet.

Consequently 2 transactions occur, and you have an influence by reattaching or promoting only on the first (the second is handled by bitfinex, so if their server is slow, the deposit will be slow)